# Why does my __file__ path contain both forward slashes and back slashes?

Tags: python, windows, python-3.x, pycharm

When I check the `__file__` variable in a script I see forward slashes up to a certain point, then the filepath switches to pairs of back slashes.

If I'm in a script under this filepath `C:\WorkFiles\python\wat_disposition\wat_disposition\__init__.py`

And I run `print(__file__)` within the script, I get the following output:

```
'C:/WorkFiles/python/wat_disposition\\wat_disposition\\__init__.py'
```

Why does it display both forward and back slashes? Shouldn't it be one or the other?

I'm concerned because I want to ensure my filepaths are valid for later file writing operations.

**Note:** I'm running python 3.x on Windows 7 in Pycharm

Comment: Exactly which version of Python is this? I can't reproduce this in 3.5.2 or 2.7.12 from the command prompt. When the module is imported you could use `__file__ = os.path.abspath(__file__)` to fix the path.

Comment: Generally it's fine to mix and match slash and backslash with the Windows API -- except not when using the ``\\?\`` prefix for extended paths. Also, command-line programs and built-in cmd.exe commands generally require backslash as the path separator because they use slash for options.

Answer (score 2):

This condition comes about when you specify a relative path to your python script. The relative path becomes part of your `__file__`, and it could become mixed with directory-separators based on both your current working directory (`%CD%`) and the relative path you called to your script.

```
import os
__file__ = os.path.abspath(__file__)
```

... does the trick, as noted by @eryksun above. `os.path.abspath()` on Windows converts it always to back-slashes. As a matter of style, I'd rather not rewrite what I think of as a constant, so I typically wrap `os.path.abspath()` around my single use of `__file__`.